# Where can I find users interested in SOA, Web services and software engineering?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I admit this is not exactly a programming question. I would highly appreciate if you could suggest me better places to send it. I tried to check whether fora at meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8401/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-programming-questions can handle such a question, but I haven't found anyone matching.

I'm organizing an experiment on collaborative tagging of Web services (http://mars.ing.unimo.it/wscolab/new.php) that would require a reasonable number of participants (i.e. taggers). I'm looking for communities that could be relevant for that. I have left my announcement at several different places for programmers, people interested in SOA, Web services, software engineering, but still I would be grateful if you could suggest me any other fora for this kind of annoucement.

Comment: This doesn't belong on Meta either...

Comment: Could you be more constructive and suggest better place to submit it, please? At least general category of places?

Answer (score 2):

> I'm organizing an experiment on collaborative tagging of Web services
>   that would require a reasonable number of participants (i.e. taggers).
>   I'm looking for communities that could be relevant for that.

All Stack Exchange sites are Q&A, so your requirement simply does not fit into any of those sites within that format. Ask yourself, what would your question be that can be answered?

However, you might have some luck in the chat rooms. If you're looking for like minded folks to join your thing, or whatever, it's not off-topic in chat rooms to ask if anyone would be interested in forming in a group (just ask in chat rooms on sites with some relevance to your cause).

Answer (score 1):

Looking for people to do something somewhere else is not the purpose of SO. So it would not be the correct forum for that i think.

Comment: I believe there is no such place on the network with the goal of: "Find participants for software engineering experiment", neither SO or any other place. That's why I decided to pose this type of question to communities related to Web services, SOA, software engineering and programming. If you know fora, mailing lists etc. related to these topics (or directories of such places), could you provide me with them? If this is still to much to ask for that, just let me know, please.